# Quasi-algebraic closure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am interested in $C_1$ fields. First of all a field $F$ is called $C_1$ field if every non-constant homogeneous polynomial $P$ over $F$ has a non-trivial zero provided the number of its variables is more than its degree and a field $F$ is called $strongly$ $C_1$ field if every polynomial without constant term $P$ over $F$ has a non-trivial zero provided the number of its variables is more than its degree. So my question is:

> Question: Is there any $C_1$ field which is not $strongly$ $C_1$?

The reason why I asked this is that every field I know which is $C_1$ especially $K(X)$, $K((X))$ and $F_q$ with $K$ algebraic closed is at least $strongly$ $C_1$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around?  Every nonconstant homogeneous polynomial lacks a constant term but a general polynomial without constant term need not be homogeneous.

Comment: Yes you are right!